# Sending Mail From Second Domain

Tags: exchange-2007, windows-sbs

I have a Windows SBS 2008 server, on which I have setup 2 domain names.

I have tested that I can send out on both.

Some users have email addresses attached to both domains, ie: JohnSmith@domainA.com JohnSmith@domainB.com

When I setup Outlook (2010) attached to DomainA email account, and then add in the account for DomainB, it won't let me send from the Domain B account. I have setup send as permissions on Exchange. Any ideas why this won't let me select a drop down to send from DomainB?

At the moment I have tried sending by typing in the email address for DomainB manually, and it comes up with permission issues.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "add in the account for DomainB"? Are you actually creating two Exchange mailboxes, associated with two different Active Directory user account? The of course you are going to have permission issues.

If the two addresses actually belong to the same user, and he must be able to choose which one use to send a message, then the correct way to accomplish this would be to add a second email address *to the existing account*, either via an address policy or by manually modifying the mailbox properties.

Comment: I'll give this a tick. It turned out to be the AD permissions. I was leaving it up to the SBS Console and Exchange mailbox management to handle the permissions, but nothing really beats adding in permissions manually in AD. Gave full mailbox rights in AD & it is now working.